# Output depend on more than 1 variable | Magento2 transaction mails

Tags: magento2

is it possible to define in Magento2 transaction mails that if one of 2 or more variables are true, only then an other variable or HTMl output is shown?

**Example:**
I only want to show a h3 headline in template, if either {{var customer_number }} OR  {{var customer_commission_number }} OR {{var customer_commentary }} are given / true.

This is my actual output and I only want to show the h3 if one of them is present:

```
<h3 margin-top:10px;>Kundeninformation</h3>

                           {{depend customer_number}}
                              {{var customer_number }}
                           {{/depend}}
                           {{depend customer_commission_number}}
                          {{var customer_commission_number }}
                           {{/depend}}
                            {{depend customer_commentary}}
                           {{var customer_commentary }}
                           {{/depend}}
```

Can someone explain me how to handle this?

Thanks in advance
Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the purpose of {{depend}} and {{if}}. The only difference between them is that {{if}} supports an {{else}} statement.
{{depend}} is just as an {{if}} without an {{else}}.
To see how they work refer to

> Varien_Filter_Template::dependDirective() and
> Varien_Filter_Template::ifDirective().